# Clear sidekiq queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've this worker that runs for ever.

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "infinity", retry: true

  def perform(params)
    # ...
    self.class.perform_in(30.seconds, params)
  end
end
```

The problem is that I load workers on start up, like this. `config/initializers/load_workers.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do  
  if ENV["SIDEKIQ"] == "1"
    Worker.perform_async({})
  end
end
```

Using this to start sidekiq `SIDEKIQ=1 sidekiq --verbose --environment production -C config/sidekiq.yml`.

This means that old workers as to stop, both those currently running but also the ones being rescheduled.

I tried running this on start up (just before loading new works), but that didn't work.

```
q = []
q += Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.select { |job| job.klass.match(/Worker/) }
q += Sidekiq::Queue.new("infinity").select { |job| job.klass.match(/Worker/) }
q += Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.select { |job| job.klass.match(/Worker/) }
q.each(&:delete)
```

After 5-ish deploys there are bunch of duplicate workers in the queue scheduled for later. So, is there a way to clear everyting in one queue and prevent already running jobs from rescheduling?

I'm using sidekiq 3.0.

Comment: Do you want to delete a queue or a scheduled job. or better to say duplicate scheduled job.

Comment: I want to delete every trace of a job before I load the new worker.

Comment: ok got your problem .. means you want to delete all the scheduled jobs.

Comment: @haSabyasachiGhosh No, I want to delete everyting related to a queue, not just the scheduled jobs. In other words; failed, ongoing, queued and scheduled jobs should be deleted.

Comment: All help is here - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API

Answer (score 203):

Deletes all Jobs in a Queue, by removing the queue.

```
require 'sidekiq/api' # for the case of rails console

Sidekiq::Queue.new("infinity").clear
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear
```

Comment: Might be **Sidekiq Pro** will help you.

Comment: Here is to clear the counters `Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset` I find out that this helps out

Comment: To clear the default/first queue: `Sidekiq::Queue.all.first.clear`

Comment: The Sidekiq::Queue.new("reports").clear and Sidekiq::Queue.new("alerts").clear helps clear the current queue. But what about Busy? How do I clear the "Busy" jobs?

Comment: Even when I kill the sidekiq process with sidekiqctl stop sidekiq.pid, the "Busy" jobs remain.

Comment: Clear them all with `Sidekiq::Queue.all.each &:clear`

Answer (score 184):

This will clear all queues, schedules and retries:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
Sidekiq::Queue.all.each(&:clear)
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear
Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.clear
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm i was into an emergency haha , the sidekick was with waaaaaay too many workers on the queue this worked as i was expecting since i was looking for `kill` like command

Comment: Perfect, just adding that in my env I had to `require 'sidekiq/api'` on console to work.

Answer (score 21):

Works for me for most sidekiq versions:

```
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear

Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear
```

Clear statistics (Optional)

```
Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset
```

Comment: This flushes the entire database, not just the queue.

Comment: if will flush all the database of sidekiq, and will work fine in rails console

Answer (score 3):

There is one more convenient way to clear all Sidekiq queues and sets for local env: `Sidekiq.redis(&:flushdb)`

Basically, it just flushes Redis that is configured for Sidekiq, so I would avoid using it in a non-local environment, as it can also remove some data you store in Redis. Anyways, it can be useful for the development or when you have a separate Redis instance for Sidekiq. And it's just one line instead of four.

Answer (score -4):

You can clear your queue by running this code although there would be built-in methods.

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new
queue.each do |job|
  job.delete 
end
```

Comment: Well, this should work as we fetched all the jobs from queue and then deleted them one by one.

Comment: No it doesn’t. Take a look at the existing answers. It’s also a duplicate of the existing answer.

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about. Can you please show me the same answer i posted?